# select box show another based on what selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to show more options via selectbox when the user selects from the main select box. I have put `display:none` for the selectboxes which will show only when the user selects option from the main select box.

can someone help me with the either jquery or javascript **only for the first option**?

```
 .sub{display:none;}

 <select> <!--This is main selectbox.-->
 <option value="">Select</option>
 <option>ONE</option>
 <option>two</option>
 <option>three</option>
 <option>four</option>
 <option>five</option>
 </select>


 <select class="sub"><!--another selectbox for option one.-->
 <option>test1</option>
 <option>test1</option>
 </select>

 <select class="sub"><!--another selectbox for option two.-->
 <option>test2</option>
 <option>test2</option>
 </select>


 <select class="sub"><!--another selectbox for option three.-->
 <option>test3</option>
 <option>test3</option>
 </select>


 <select class="sub"><!--another selectbox for option four.-->
 <option>test4</option>
 <option>test4</option>
 </select>


 <select class="sub"><!--another selectbox for option five.-->
 <option>test5</option>
 <option>test5</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM Select Element has `selectedIndex` property which specifies the index of the selected Option, by using jQuery `.eq()` method, this property and listening to `change` event  you can select the target select element from jQuery index-based collection:

```
var $sub = $('select.sub');

$('select').first().change(function() {    
    $sub.hide();
    // If the first option is not selected
    if (this.selectedIndex > 0)
       $sub.eq(this.selectedIndex - 1).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7CmYj/

Comment: thanks works perfect. Can I do the same thing if I want to have another third selectbox based on what selected on the second selectobox by changing the class?

Comment: @amdvb You are welcome, yes, if you know what you are doing everything that makes sense is possible.